# Passing multiple values for one SQL parameter

Tags: sql-server-2005, t-sql, checkboxlist, where-in

I have a CheckBoxList where users can select multiple items from the list. I then need to be able to pass these values to my Stored Procedure so they can be used in a WHERE condition like:

```
WHERE ID IN (1,2,3)
```

I tried doing this so that its a nvarchar parameter and i pass the string `1,2,3` with:

```
WHERE ID IN (@IDs)
```

But this returned the following error:

```
Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '1,2,3' to data type int
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/878833/passing-a-varchar-full-of-comma-delimited-values-to-a-sql-server-in-function (or use a bitmask)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There's a few ways of doing it. 
You could pass in the parameter as an XML blob like this example:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[uspGetCustomersXML]
    @CustomerIDs XML
AS
BEGIN
SELECT c.ID, c.Name
FROM [dbo].[Customer] c
JOIN @CustomerIDs.nodes('IDList/ID') AS x(Item) ON c.ID = Item.value('.', 'int' )
END
GO

--Example Use:
EXECUTE [dbo].[uspGetCustomersXML] '<IDList><ID>1</ID><ID>10</ID><ID>100</ID></IDList>'
```

Or pass in the values as CSV and use a split function to split the values out into a table variable (there's a lot of split functions out there, quick search will throw one up).

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[uspGetCustomersCSV]
    @CustomerIDs VARCHAR(8000)
AS
BEGIN
SELECT c.Id, c.Name
FROM [dbo].[Customer] c
JOIN dbo.fnSplit(@CustomerIDs, ',') t ON c.Id = t.item
END
GO

--Example Use:
EXECUTE [dbo].[uspGetCustomersCSV] '1,10,100'
```

If you were using SQL 2008 or later, you could have used Table Valued Parameters which allow you to pass a TABLE variable in as a parameter. I [blogged](http://www.adathedev.co.uk/2010/02/sql-server-2008-table-valued-parameters.html) about these 3 approaches a while back, with a quick performance comparison.

Comment: Thanks for this. I used a WHERE IN (SELECT [values from XML]) clause to get results but never would've known this was possible previously. Cheers!

Comment: @Curt how to use the `[values from XML])` term in the  `WHERE IN (SELECT [values from XML])` do you have a specific code? can you help me? sorry im new to this.

Answer (score 1):

```
alter procedure c2
(@i varchar(5))
as
begin
    declare @sq nvarchar(4000)
    set @sq= 'select * from test where id in (<has_i>) '
    SET @sq= REPLACE(@sq, '<has_i>', @i)
    EXECUTE sp_executesql  @sq
end

exec c2 '1,3'
```

Answer (score -1):

I did find a solution for a similar problem. 
It is used for a data driven subscription, but can be easily altered for use in a parameter.
[check my blog post here with a detailed description](http://www.tricks-and-tips.nl/?p=58)

If you are having problem converting it to a stored procedure call, just let me know.

Comment: Can you expand a little your answer? Near link-only answers are not useful if the link ever goes broken.

Comment: Sorry, I was rather late..... I will convert the blogpost into separate replies. For the whole story : the blogpost still works!

Comment: It is a rather lengthy blog post and it is still online (and will be for some time)

Comment: I have created a very simple table with the name tmpMultiSel with two columns (ID and Name)

Comment: Here is what I did to make it ‘multi value’:

1.       Create a function

I did find a function that accepts two parameters and splits the delimited string (first parameter) into a temporary table.

I found it http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7938/SQL-User-Defined-Function-to-Parse-a-Delimited-Str but modified the name to my ‘habits’ _f_ParseText2Table

If we test this function, it works like so:

Comment: Meaning we can actually use this function to split a delimited string to a tempory table that we can join or select in a ‘IN’ clause (WHERE … IN (SELECT txt_value FROM dbo._f_ParseText2Table(‘1,2,3′,’,’))

2.       Create a report

Next I created a report that has a dataset that links to the tmpMultiSel table (but could also link to a transactional table, that would make more sense)

Comment: SELECT
*
FROM tmpMultiSel
The second dataset is used to give the user the possibility  to multi select some values from a table:

Comment: The trick here is that this parameter (IDSel) may be left blank (as we cannot pass multiple values to a parameter via query or Data Driven Subscription) AND that we add an empty line in the second dataset (UNION ALL SELECT ”,”) to be able to select the ” value from the Data Driven Subscription. (make sure you type 2x single quotes comma 2x single quotes)

3.       Create a parameter

Here we have a parameter (ID) that we pass to the function:

Comment: In ‘real life’ we would hide this parameter, but for testing purpose it is nicer to watch how it works.

We add a second parameter (IDSel) that has multiple values and the available values selected from the second dataset.

Comment: We set the default value for the first parameter (ID) to the split values of the second parameter (IDSel)

As we test this report, it works like a charm, passing the two selected ID’s to the ID parameter, which in return passes its values to the first dataset.  (what would be the transactional table)

Comment: 4.       Create the data driven subscription

Now that we know this report works ‘interactive’ we can proceed to the data driven subscription.
I’ve used a simple dataset that only has three columns (ID, IDSel and Mail).

I did just select some static values, but you can easily modify it to work with a ‘real’ example where you select data from a table.

Now we map this three columns to the appropriate fields and create a schedule for this subscription (once).