# passing more then one value with the querystring with the same id

Tags: asp.net, query-string

I have a datalist that I want to list the Products that are comming from the Querystring. It works like this: `Default.aspx/?ProductID=1` 
I get 1 product like I want.
But I want to add more products like this `Default.aspx/?ProductID=1,15,25` 
and get three products back. How do I make that to work?

```
<asp:DataList ID="DataList1" runat="server">
    <ItemStyle VerticalAlign="Top" />
    <ItemTemplate>
        <a href="../Product/Default.aspx?ProductID=<%#Eval("ProductID") %>">
            <asp:Label ID="lblName" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Name") %>' />
            <asp:Label ID="lblPrice" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Price") %>' />
        </a>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>


  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string id = Request.QueryString["ProductID"];

    DataTable table = CategoryAccess.GetList(id);

    list.DataSource = table;
    list.DataBind();     
}


ALTER PROCEDURE GetList
@ProductID INT

AS
SELECT ProductID, Name, Price 
FROM Product
WHERE (ProductID = @ProductID)
```

Comment: When using query strings never forget that they are, well, strings. What would the app do if I request, Default.aspx/?ProductID=Nicklas

Comment: I made the code shorter and more simpel just to make it short here. If the number dosent match the database a label whith a error messages will appear.

Answer (score 2):

You can have:

```
/page.aspx?ProductID=1&ProductID=15&ProductID=25
```

Then `Request.Querystring("ProductID")` will return `1,15,25`

This can then be put into an `ArrayList` like `Request.Querystring("ProductID").split(",")`

Passing those 3 values as a parameter is a bit more tricky though, youre probably best passing it as xml:

[Passing multiple values for one SQL parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4624398/passing-multiple-values-for-one-sql-parameter)