# How to pass the two values of checkbox to a same variable in response.redirect in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

This is the code i used to passing 1 value:

```
 if (Chbk_NewProject.Checked )
 {
     Response.Redirect("PropertiedDetailsByTypeList.aspx?id=" + 1 + "&text=" + HF_SEARCH.Value);
 }
 if (Chbk_Resale.Checked)
 {
    Response.Redirect("PropertiedDetailsByTypeList.aspx?id=" + 2 + "&text=" + HF_SEARCH.Value);
 }
 if (Chbk_Resale.Checked)
 {
    Response.Redirect("PropertiedDetailsByTypeList.aspx?id=" + 3 + "&text=" + HF_SEARCH.Value);
  }
```

I want to pass multiple value in response.redirect.

For example:

```
 if (Chbk_NewProject.Checked && Chbk_Resale.Checked )
 {
    Response.Redirect("PropertiedDetailsByTypeList.aspx?id=" + 1 + "&text=" + HF_SEARCH.Value);
 }
```

In this both checkbox value need to pass..Can anyone help me please?

Comment: add another queryString parameter value

Comment: What are you getting btw ?

Comment: Retrieve the data of the checkbox checked from database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Anju Muralidharan try this..

```
    if (Chbk_NewProject.Checked && Chbk_Resale.Checked )
     {
       Response.Redirect("PropertiedDetailsByTypeList.aspx?id1=1&id1=2&text=" + HF_SEARCH.Value);
                                                         ---^  ---^
     }

Then Request.Querystring("id1") will return 1,2

This can then be put into an ArrayList like Request.Querystring("id").split(",")
```

like this.. 
field1=value1&field1=value2&field1=value3...

[passing more then one value with the querystring with the same id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5218452/passing-more-then-one-value-with-the-querystring-with-the-same-id)

Answer (score 0):

If understood your requirement correctly then try below solution. if you want to pass both value to query string then you have to add two new variables to store these values.

```
 if (Chbk_NewProject.Checked && Chbk_Resale.Checked )
 {
   Response.Redirect("PropertiedDetailsByTypeList.aspx?id1=1&id2=2&text=" + HF_SEARCH.Value);
                                                     ---^  ---^
 }
```

Comment: I want to pass the two value  to same id1,not to another id2

Comment: ok, then you may try like this `id=1-2` you can use any separator you want but on redirected page you may need to some more code to separate those id's.