# Handling the multiple values for single key in the API URL

Tags: c#, .net, rest, aws-api-gateway

I need to handle the multiple values for the single key in the URL.

Ex: 
  values/{values}  => values/1,2,3

I refered the following URL: [REST API Best practice: How to accept list of parameter values as input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2602043/rest-api-best-practice-how-to-accept-list-of-parameter-values-as-input)

But still i am thinking best practices to pass multiple values. And i need to know which is standard way to pass the values in the route.

Comment: The standard way to post the data in the body and parse it, instead of URL. You should use HttpPost request.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [passing more then one value with the querystring with the same id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5218452/passing-more-then-one-value-with-the-querystring-with-the-same-id)