# Passing multiple values to a parameter of a function in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2012

There is function `Getfunctionname(userid, startdate, enddate)` to return a table

My question is can I pass a variable with multiple values?

i.e.

```
getfunctionname(@userid, startdate, enddate)
```

Where the value of variable `@userid` is like

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

(actually using `split` function splitting the values from being `1,2,3,4,5` )

If I can please let me know

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4624398/passing-multiple-values-for-one-sql-parameter

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing a varchar full of comma delimited values to a SQL Server IN function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/878833/passing-a-varchar-full-of-comma-delimited-values-to-a-sql-server-in-function)

Answer (score 2):

One way of doing that which I prefer is to make a new user-defined table data type.

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[IdList] AS TABLE(
    [Id] [int] NULL
)
```

Then you can use that data type as one of the parameters

```
CREATE FUNCTION Getfunctionname
(   
    @UserIDs dbo.IdList READONLY,
    @startdate INT,
    @endtdate INT
     )
RETURNS @ReturnTable TABLE                                        
   (                                        
     -- ReturnTable
   )
AS
BEGIN
  -- Query    
RETURN

END
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the concept of `CSV`

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[uspGetNumbers]
    userid,startdate,enddate // define your paramters the way you want
AS
BEGIN
// your code
JOIN dbo.fnSplit(@UserIDs, ',') 
END
GO
```

Example function:

```
SELECT [dbo].[uspGetNumbers] '1,2,3,4,5', '', ''
```

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this, and I used the CROSS APPLY solution from this post:
[SQL Server: run function for each row based on the provided row value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40780274/sql-server-run-function-for-each-row-based-on-the-provided-row-value)

To use CROSS APPLY, you would need to first select your values, and then CROSS APPLY. I have not used the split function before, so I don't have the exact syntax,
but if you use it something like:

select @userid, F1.* from split(1,2,3,4,5),
CROSS APPLY getfunctionname(@userid, startdate, enddate) F1