# Any way to build string to be used in WHERE IN()?

Tags: t-sql

I am using SQL Server 2005.

I am using some string functions, to generate a string back that is always in this format:

Number,Number,Number,Number

I am attempting to use this generated string like so:

```
select LastName from User 
Where ID in (
subtring(<returning the format shown above>)
)
```

I keep getting the error:
Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Line 3
Error converting data type varchar to numeric.

This makes sense, that if WHERE IN() is passed in a string, that it would not work - since usually it is accepting comma seperated true integers.

Is there any way to accomplish what I'm trying here?

Thank you!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Passing a varchar full of comma delimited values to a SQL Server IN function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/878833/passing-a-varchar-full-of-comma-delimited-values-to-a-sql-server-in-function)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dynamic SQL should do the trick.

```
declare @ids varchar(100) set @ids = '1,2,3,4,5,6,7'

declare @sql nvarchar(200) set @sql = N'select LastName from User Where ID in (' + @ids + N')'

exec sp_executesql @sql
```

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933299(v=sql.80).aspx

Comment: Caveat to this approach is that it can be prone to SQL injection attacks.