# How to use a SQL SELECT IN statement in an ASP.net tableadapter

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server

I've been struggling with this all day - been all over SO and Google and can't find anything to help. I have a SQL query in an XSD tableadapter that looks something like this:

```
SELECT column A, column B, column C
FROM Table
WHERE variable1 = @UserID
AND variable2 IN (@ListOfItems)
```

Variable 2 is an int32 column.

So, I want to pass a comma-separated list of values to the @ListOfItems parameter. However, whenever I try, no matter how I configure the adapter (change the provider and data types for the parameter), it just kicks up and says "Conversion failed converting the varchar value '1,2,3' to data type int.

I can see that the string I'm generating is valid - if I copy the query into a SQL editor and hard code the string, it works fine.

Is what I'm trying to do even possible with a tableadapter?

Any help is appreciated beyond measure.

Comment: You might find your answer here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18513441/sql-parameter-with-multiple-values

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("select Colum A,Colum B,Colum C from Table where variable1 =" + @userID + "and variable1 in ("+@listofitems+")", yourConnectionObject);
```

but @userID , @listofitems is varaible in ASP.NET in my example

Comment: I think this solution suffers from sql injection vulnerability.

Comment: This does exactly what I need. SQL Injection is not an issue as the code is generating the list of values - they don't come from a user input. Thanks everyone for the very swift and very useful replies

Comment: Not necessarily only a SQL injection issue. Make sure you replace any quotation marks in your parameters as that will break the SQL as well

Comment: Thanks Sameer. My parameters are all integers so no problems there!. Good point to watch out for when using strings though.

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at [Arrays and Lists in SQL Server](http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql-2005.html#CSV)

Comment: Yeah unfortunately this is not an easy solution. I can tell you at my last gig we used a CLR object @IntTable.  That worked really well.  But it requires you creating a new SQL server CLR type and deploying it to the server. I believe he discusses this in the writeup