# How to improve performance for query with CHARINDEX?

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

Suppose I have a table

```
MyTab (ID int, MyNo varchar(50),.....)
```

There is a index on the `MyNo` column.

Then I have following SQL query:

```
declare @Nos varchar(100000)
set  @Nos = ',001,002,003,004,'

Select * 
from MyTab
Where CHARINDEX(',' + MyNo + ', @Nos) > 0
```

It is fine when the string `@Nos` is short. But if `@Nos` is larger, say length is 10000, the query performance is pretty bad.

How to improve the performance for this case? Or better solution to replace the query?

Comment: Better solution would be to change DB design. Instead of keeping comma separated list of numbers in a column, create another table that would list one number per row and foreign key pointing to ID in MyTab

Comment: possible duplicate of [Passing a varchar full of comma delimited values to a SQL Server IN function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/878833/passing-a-varchar-full-of-comma-delimited-values-to-a-sql-server-in-function)

Comment: As far as I know, a `VARCHAR` cannot be larger than 8000 characters.....

Answer (score 2):

I posted this approach as a tongue-in-cheek answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/878833/109122).  Unfortunately, too many people take it seriously.  Though it's OK for ad-hoc querying, it's really not appropriate for production.  The accepted answer at that question is much better and can address your performance problem also.