# Mysql - IN clause in procedure for delaring cursor in procedure

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

Please help me..
I am declaring cursor with IN clause value getting from other table where the value will be with comma (,) seprated and storing that into a variable and giving to the IN clause.

Here is my code:

```
CREATE  DEFINER=`xxx`@`%`  PROCEDURE `procedurename`(
OUT examDetails VARCHAR(2500)
)
BEGIN

DECLARE v_examType VARCHAR(50);
DECLARE v_minMarks INT(10);
DECLARE v_time INT(10);
DECLARE v_noOfQuestions INT(10);
DECLARE v_subTopicIds VARCHAR(50);
DECLARE v_subtopicname VARCHAR(50);
DECLARE v_result VARCHAR(2500) DEFAULT '';
DECLARE v_temp INT(20);



DECLARE cur1 CURSOR FOR SELECT ExamType,MinMarks,TIME,NoOfQuestions,SubTopicIds FROM tblCreSetExam;


 select ExamType,MinMarks,Time,NoOfQuestions,SubTopicIds from tblCreSetExam
OPEN cur1;
    FETCH FROM cur1 INTO v_examType,v_minMarks,v_time,v_noOfQuestions,v_subTopicIds;

     declare cur2 cursor for select SubTopicName from tblEcertSubTopics where Id in (v_subTopicIds);




    v_result = CONCAT(v_result,v_examType,'!',v_minMarks,'!',v_time,'!',v_noOfQuestions,'!');
    open cur2;
        fetch from cur2 into v_subtopicname;

        v_result = CONCAT(v_result,v_subtopicname,'!');

     close cur2;
        v_temp = LENGTH(v_result)-1;
        v_result = SUBSTRING(v_result,1,v_temp);
        v_result = CONCAT(v_result,'^')


CLOSE cur1;



SET examDetails = v_result;

END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

But i am getting this error:

> Error Code : 1064
>       You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
>       MySQLserver version for the right syntax to use near 'declare cur2 cursor for select
>       column1 from table1 where Id in (' at line 20

do any one know why this is getting..
Thanks in advance

Comment: You appear to have a random select in the middle of your code, which is also missing a ; from the end. As to the IN clause, you appear to be using an IN with only a single item in the brackets. Might be better to just use a JOIN.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There exist multiple errors in your code.

**Error 1**:

```
FETCH FROM cur1 INTO v_examType,v_minMarks,v_time,v_noOfQuestions,v_subTopicIds;
```

Change it to:

```
FETCH cur1 INTO v_examType,v_minMarks,v_time,v_noOfQuestions,v_subTopicIds;
```

Error was due to presence of `FROM`. It was not required.

**Error 2**:

Change

```
v_result = CONCAT(v_result,'^')
```

To:

```
v_result = CONCAT(v_result,'^');
```

Semi-colon is missing.

Comment: modified my procedure  please check again and i am getting error as
Error Code : 1064
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'close cur1;
 set examDetails = v_result;
 
    END' at line 47

Comment: removed from but not effected Please help

Comment: append semi-colon next to `v_result = CONCAT(v_result,'^')`. It is missing.

Comment: Ravinder : how can i cast from varchar to int and store in a variable and then give that to a query..please help

Comment: I believe this is for your `in` clause but the query was not that clear. post new question with valid input and required result values.

Comment: called procedure CALL procedurename(@result);
Query : call spGetCreExamDetails(@result)

Error Code : 1054
Unknown column 'v_subTopicsIds' in 'field list'
Pleas help me

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use an IN CLAUSE with a VARCHAR variable.

This will not work:

```
where Id in (v_subTopicIds)
```

Perhaps do what you are trying in code instead of a SQL procedure, otherwise you need to rethink your strategy

Comment: OK how can i cast from varchar to int and store in a variable and then i can give that to my query ??

Comment: Have a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/878833/passing-a-varchar-full-of-comma-delimited-values-to-a-sql-server-in-function