# SSIS comma delimited string in where clause

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I am trying to see if there is an easy answer for this.  I have done something similar using multiple pick dropdown parameters in SSRS but this appears to be different.

My scenario is this, so maybe there is an even better answer.

I have a production server that I do not want to make any changes to including temp tables or functions.  The production server has a table of clients with about 1600 records.  I have set up an SSIS package that will allow transfer of data from production to dev based on a clientid.  So my sources would have a query similar to Select Field From Table Where ClientId = ?

This works fine.  Now I want to load more than one client, based an data in the clients table.  It may be Select ClientId From Clients where Field = A and returns multiple ClientIds.

I am able to populate a comma delimited list from an execute sql task to a SSIS variable, so it maybe 1,4,8.

If I change my source query to use ClientId in (?) I get a conversion error.

I have looked at many posts that advocate a temp table or a function which I want to avoid.  [Select IN using varchar string with comma delimited values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27022145/select-in-using-varchar-string-with-comma-delimited-values)

I have contemplated building the entire sql statement into a variable but this don't seem like the right path as I have many tables to query and transfer where using ClientId = ? works well without having to build each individual SQL statement to a variable.

Is there an easy fix I am missing?  I will turn my research now to try to find out how I did this in SSRS but I thought that I should try a post here to see if someone has accomplished this before.

I appreciate any info on this, thank you.

EDIT:  Key note is that the column on clients is on the dev server, so I cannot just use a select in the where clause as the column does not exist on the production server.

EDIT:  I did not mention that I am specifically looking at OLEDB sources mapping a parameter to ? in the sql statement.

EDIT: Narrowing down on this but having trouble relating SSRS and SSIS functionality.  In SSRS its called a multi-value parameter in the following link the key line is

> WHERE   Production.ProductInventory.ProductID IN (@ProductID)

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn385719(v=sql.110).aspx

This one looks good as well
https://sqlblogcasts.com/blogs/simons/archive/2007/11/22/RS-HowTo---Pass-a-multivalue-parameter-to-a-query-using-IN.aspx

I will keep researching and thank you for the help so far.

I think this sums it up best

> This functionality is limited to strictly using embedded SQL.
>
> What SSRS does is transform your SQL column IN (@value) to column IN
>   (@selectedvalue1,@selectedvalue2) etc.
>
> You need to forget anything you have about the other ways of passing
>   lists to SQL i.e. building strings etc. and make sure you declare the
>   data types are correct for the value of your parameter.
>
> You do not need to use the Join(parameters!,",") trick UNLESS
>   you are passing the list to a stored procedure.
>
> In which case you then need to use some function to turn the delimited
>   list into a rowset as you have done.
>
> I hope that helps

The core question is if I can get the same functionality in SSIS as in SSRS.  It reminds me of macro substitution..

Comment: You have about three choices, use a table valued parameter instead of a delimited list, use a split function or use dynamic sql. That is pretty much about the only choices you have.

Answer (score 0):

If you dont want to create a function, you can use the following in your t-sql statement.

```
 Declare @ClientIds nvarchar(50) = '123,456'; --<-- Comma delimited list of Client Ids


 Select Field 
 From Table 
 Where ClientId IN (
                    SELECT  CAST(RTRIM(LTRIM(Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)'))) AS INT) ClientIDs
                    FROM (
                            SELECT Cast ('<X>' 
                                        + Replace(@ClientIds, ',', '</X><X>') 
                                        + '</X>' AS XML) AS Data
                            ) AS t CROSS APPLY Data.nodes ('/X') AS Split(a) 
                    )
```

Comment: This looks cool, I will try this.  I just feel I am missing something more simple with SSIS parameters in OLEDB sources.

Comment: I tried it out and it is a nice solution that I might use in another case.  I feel this is more related to SSIS parameters and would not work in this case.