# Using a comma-separated parameter in an IN clause

Tags: sql, t-sql, stored-procedures, reporting-services, parameters

I have `'param1, param2, parma3'` coming from SSRS to a stored procedure as a `varchar` parameter: I need to use it in a query's `IN` clause but then need to change its format like this first:

```
select *
from table1
where col1 in('param1', 'param2', 'param3')
```

What is the best way to reformat the parameter without creating functions and parameter tables?

Comment: Parse it in SP and create temp table.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Passing a varchar full of comma delimited values to a SQL Server IN function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/878833/passing-a-varchar-full-of-comma-delimited-values-to-a-sql-server-in-function)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try this one, Just need to add commas at the beginning and at the end of @params string.

```
Declare @params varchar(100) Set @params = ',param1,param2,param3,'

Select * from t
where CHARINDEX(','+cast(col1 as varchar(8000))+',', @params) > 0
```

[SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/71c5d/1)

Comment: Heads up that this yields `Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 15  Incorrect syntax near ','.` with a red squigly under the comma following `',param1'` when I execute it.

Answer (score 7):

you can use split function and use it as in following way
here my split fnSplitString return splitdata

```
select * from tb1 where id in(select splitdata from dbo.fnSplitString((select col1 from tb12 where id=3),','))


create FUNCTION [dbo].[fnSplitString] 
( 
    @string NVARCHAR(MAX), 
    @delimiter CHAR(1) 
) 
RETURNS @output TABLE(splitdata NVARCHAR(MAX) 
) 
BEGIN 
    DECLARE @start INT, @end INT 
    SELECT @start = 1, @end = CHARINDEX(@delimiter, @string) 
    WHILE @start < LEN(@string) + 1 BEGIN 
        IF @end = 0  
            SET @end = LEN(@string) + 1

        INSERT INTO @output(splitdata)  
        VALUES(SUBSTRING(@string, @start, @end - @start)) 
        SET @start = @end + 1 
        SET @end = CHARINDEX(@delimiter, @string, @start)

    END 
    RETURN 
END
```

Comment: The OP's question specifed, "what is the best way to reformat the parameter without creating functions and parameter tables". Given that, I assume they were aware of this approach, but didn't want to create an e.g. `fnSplitString` function.That's also what sets this question apart from [other similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/878833/passing-a-varchar-full-of-comma-delimited-values-to-a-sql-server-in-function).

Answer (score 7):

If you are using SQL 2016 and above `string_split` you can use.

```
-- @param is where you keep your comma separated values example: 
declare @param = 'param1,param2,param3'
select * from table1 where col1 in (select TRIM(value) from string_split(@param,',')
```

More information about string_split check [offical documemt](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Furthermore, `TRIM()` is used to trim values from white spaces.

Answer (score 5):

We can use [STRING_SPLIT()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) in SQL SERVER

```
DECLARE @params varchar(max)= 'param1,param2,param3'

SELECT *
FROM table1
WHERE col1 IN (SELECT value FROM STRING_SPLIT( @params , ','))
```

Answer (score 1):

"Best way" is arguable, but one classic approach that remains without "creating functions and table parameters" is to simply employ dynamic SQL in the stored procedure:

```
-- FORNOW: local to act as the SP param and arg
declare @values varchar(100) = 'param1, param2, param3'

-- Add opening and closing single quotes, then quotes around each
-- comma-separated list item.
select @values = '''' + REPLACE(@values, ', ', ''', ''') + ''''

-- FORNOW: for clarity/debugging
print @values
--'param1', 'param2', 'param3'

-- Run the desired query as dynamic SQL.
DECLARE @sql as nvarchar(250);
SET @sql = 'select * from table1 where col1 in (' + @values + ')';

EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```

This assumes a couple things, though:

1. That commas in the list of values are followed by a space.  Variations on this solution can address deviations in this respect of course, but it is important to be aware of this assumption.
2. That the comma-separated values do not themselves have commas in them – unlikely but worth mentioning since whether values will satisfy this constraint sometimes goes unconsidered.

Answer (score 0):

Load the Params into a string and execute as an sql :

```
declare @param varchar(1000) = 'param1, param2, parma3'
declare @sql varchar(4000)
select @sql = 
'select *
from table1
where col1 in(''' + replace(@param,',',''',''') + ''')'

-- print @sql -- to see what you're going to execute
exec sp_executesql @sql
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @params varchar(max) = '1,2,3,4'

SELECT * FROM table2 WHERE colId IN (SELECT value FROM SPLIT(@params,','))
```

Base on id we can find.

Comment: What's the difference between `SPLIT()` and `STRING_SPLIT()` used in very similar existing answers? In fact, are you even certain `SPLIT()` is a function in Microsoft SQL Server? (I don't believe it is.)