# stored procedure selecting multiple record id

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I have a collection of record ids(x,y,z,..) which is pass to a stored procedure as a string value. My stored procedure is:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Sp_Getvalue](@recordId varchar(30)) 
AS
BEGIN    
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    select  
    x.record_Id,
    x.name,
    x.address from dbo.tblvalue x where x.record_Id in (@recordId)
END
```

in code behind

```
var obj = context.Sp_Getvalue(value);
```

I am getting error as

> An exception of type 'System.Data.EntityCommandExecutionException' occurred in System.Data.Entity.dll but was not handled in user code

Comment: Please learn to format your code in the future.

Comment: That's the message that terminates your application, not the real exception. Debug your code and check what the EntityCommandExecutionException tells you. Even better, add a try/catch around your code and log the full exception

Comment: I don't believe you can directly do an `... in @IdList`, Read this article http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/584680/Using-comma-separated-value-parameter-strings-in-S

Comment: possible duplicate of [Passing a varchar full of comma delimited values to a SQL Server IN function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/878833/passing-a-varchar-full-of-comma-delimited-values-to-a-sql-server-in-function)

Comment: By the way, as long as we're here:   it's generally frowned upon to use a comma-delimited string to pass multiple IDs to a stored procedure.  (For example:  what if you passed so many IDs that your `varchar(30)` variable wasn't long enough?)  Try using an XML variable instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can not use the parameter directly in IN clause
Please check the following syntax where I used a [SQL split string function](http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/t-sql-convert-split-delimeted-string-as-rows-using-xml.aspx)

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Sp_Getvalue](@recordId varchar(30)) 
AS
BEGIN    
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    select  
        x.record_Id,
        x.name,
        x.address 
    from dbo.tblvalue x 
    where 
        x.record_Id in (
            select val from dbo.split(@recordId,',')
        )
END
```

You can copy the split function codes from here: http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/t-sql-convert-split-delimeted-string-as-rows-using-xml.aspx
and create on your target database

Answer (score 0):

You cannot directly use the comma separated values in `IN` clause and no need of any create any functions for that. There are two approaches to do that

**1. Use `Dynamic Sql` to get records according to values in `@recordId`**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Sp_Getvalue](@recordId varchar(30)) 
AS
BEGIN    
SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @query NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @query = 'INSERT INTO TABLETOINSERT(COL,COL2,COL3)
              SELECT record_Id,name,address 
              FROM tblvalue 
              WHERE record_Id IN('+@recordId+')' 

EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @query

END
```

- [Click here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5fdaf/1) to view result

If you do not want to insert, and just want select statement, remove the 
`INSERT INTO TABLETOINSERT(COL,COL2,COL3)` from the dynamic sql.

**2. Using `XML` format to split comma separated values to row and using `IN`**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Sp_Getvalue](@recordId varchar(30)) 
AS
BEGIN    
SET NOCOUNT ON;


INSERT INTO TABLETOINSERT(COL1,COL2,COL3)
SELECT record_Id,NAME,[ADDRESS]
FROM tblvalue
WHERE record_Id IN
(
    -- Convert comma separated values to rows
    SELECT LTRIM(RTRIM(Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)'))) 'KeyWords' 
    FROM  
    (        
         SELECT CAST ('<M>' + REPLACE(@recordId, ',', '</M><M>') + '</M>' AS XML) AS Data      
    ) AS A 
    CROSS APPLY Data.nodes ('/M') AS Split(a)
)

END
```

- [Click here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5fdaf/3) to view result