# SQL Server : make a select and test every occurrence/row inside another select

Tags: sql-server

I have a SQL Server stored procedure that receives a comma separated string as parameter.

I also have a table-valued function that takes this parameter, splits it (between the commas) and returns as a 'table'.

This procedures is a 'search procedure' that uses `LIKE` operator to find matching terms.

How can I loop through this parameter that has been transformed into a table and compare it with `LIKE`?

The sequence that I'd need is something like this:

1. SQL Server procedure has been called and a separated comma string has been passed as parameter.
2. A table-valued function gets called to strip this string and transform it in a result table. (It´s not a real table, its just the results). Until here I have already done, the next part is the one I need help:
3. Loop through this recently created 'table' and search in a specific column of another table.

eg.

```
SELECT * 
FROM tbl_names 
WHERE col_names LIKE '%' + (the search term here) + '%'
```

Comment: You don't need a loop, just INNER JOIN the tables together using your WHERE clause above as the join condition.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Passing a varchar full of comma delimited values to a SQL Server IN function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/878833/passing-a-varchar-full-of-comma-delimited-values-to-a-sql-server-in-function)

Answer (score 1):

You can join your table on result of your function:

```
select * from SomeTable st
join dbo.SomeFunction(@str) sf on st.SomeColumn like '%' + sf.Term +'%'
```

To order by occurences do something like this:

```
select * from SomeTable st
join(
    select st.ID, count(*) as Occurence from SomeTable st
    join dbo.SomeFunction(@str) sf on st.SomeColumn like '%' + sf.Term +'%'
    group by st.ID) ot on st.ID = ot.ID
order by ot.Occurence desc
```

Comment: That´s  pretty much it, I´m just trying to figure out how to order by  biggest number of occurrences, so in case two terms are in the same row, they should be first/before the ocurrences that has only one term matched.

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably use a cross or outer apply with patindex if you want to know how many items matched

```
select S.*, m.matches 
from sometable s
cross apply (select count(1) as matches from finction where patindex ('%' + function.Column + '%', s.coltosearch) > 1) as matched
```

Use cross apply if you only want to return rows that have matches and outer if you want all rows with a count of terms.

*Note: Code example is untested*