# How to use escape with LIKE in SQL Query

Tags: sql, t-sql

My Query is :

```
declare @param1 INT,
@param2 nvarchar(max)

set @param1 = 1
set @param2 = '[Test_data_forQry],[Next_Test_Data]'

SELECT * 
FROM Table1
WHERE
    ColumnA = @param1  
AND (',' + @param2 +',' LIKE '%,' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, ColumnB) + ',%');
```

The square brackets and underscore is blocking the data fetch. My question is where should I place **escape '\'** in the last line of query.
I also tried **`REPLACE`** option, but didn't work

```
set @param1 = 1
set @param2 = '[Test_data_forQry],[Next_Test_Data]'

set @param2  = replace (replace(@param2  , '[', '[[]'), '_','[_]') 

SELECT * 
FROM Table1
WHERE
    ColumnA = @param1  
AND (',' + @param2 +',' LIKE '%,' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, ColumnB) + ',%');
```

Comment: The square brackets and underscore in @param2 are not the problem. The problem is that those characters are in ColumnB, after the `LIKE`. What is in ColumnB, a single bracketed name like `[Test_data_forQry]`?

Comment: Yes, ColumB has data like [Test_data_forQry] .. a direct query fetches data
like
 select * from Table where ColumnA=1 and ColumnB like '%[[]Test[_]data[_]forQry]%'

Comment: Use CHARINDEX insstead of LIKE, when you search values with "[]"

Comment: I  don't know what is the correction needed in the below qry, i'm only getting one record using Charindex 
Modified Query : select * FROM Table1   WHERE     ColumnA =  param1 AND CHARINDEX(',' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, ColumnB)    +','  ,  param2 )>0;

Comment: The XML usage seems to work

Declare Ids varchar(50)
Set Ids = ‘1,2,3,5,4,6,7,98,234’

DECLARE XML XML
SET XML = CAST('<i>' + REPLACE(@Ids, ',', '</i><i>') + '</i>' AS XML)

SELECT * 
FROM
    SomeTable 
    INNER JOIN XML.nodes('i') x(i) 
        ON  SomeTable .Id = x.i.value('.', 'VARCHAR(MAX)')

http://stackoverflow.com/a/16936683/3315245

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape all LIKE characters first and use [ESCAPE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx#code-snippet-8) operator.  Also, your conversion of ColumnB to VARCHAR is by default only VARCHAR(30) so data in ColumnB was being truncated and not matching since, by itself, @param2 is 35 characters unescaped.

See below:

```
DECLARE @param1 INT, @param2 NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @param1 = 1
SET @param2 = '[Test_data_forQry],[Next_Test_Data]'

-- Replace LIKE special characters
SET @param2 = REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(@param2, '[', '|['), ']', '|]'), '%', '|%'), '_', '|_')

SELECT *
FROM Table1
WHERE
    ColumnA = @param1  
    AND CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), ColumnB) LIKE ('%,' + @param2 +',%') ESCAPE '|';
```

**Edit:** if your ColumnB data does have example data like '[Test_data_forQry]' that you indicated in one of you comments, then leave it switched around like so and escape ColumnB instead of @param2:

```
DECLARE @param1 INT, @param2 NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @param1 = 1
SET @param2 = '[Test_data_forQry],[Next_Test_Data]'

SELECT *
FROM Table1
WHERE
    ColumnA = @param1  
    AND @param2 LIKE '%' + REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), ColumnB), '[', '|['), ']', '|]'), '%', '|%'), '_', '|_') + '%' ESCAPE '|';
```

Not great for performance likely with so much happening in the where, but this will match a row with ColumnA = 1 and ColumnB = '[Test_data_forQry]'.

**Update:**
Updated to split the search string on commas (will likely need to create a function from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/314824/t-sql-opposite-to-string-concatenation-how-to-split-string-into-multiple-reco) first):

```
DECLARE @param1 INT, @param2 NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @param1 = 1
SET @param2 = '[Test_data_forQry],[Next_Test_Data]'

-- Replace LIKE special characters
SET @param2 = REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(@param2, '[', '|['), ']', '|]'), '%', '|%'), '_', '|_')

SELECT DISTINCT t.*
FROM Table1 t
    INNER JOIN dbo.split(@param2, ',') split ON 1=1
WHERE
    t.ColumnA = @param1  
    AND CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), t.ColumnB) LIKE ('%' + split.s + '%') ESCAPE '|';
```

Comment: Yes it fetches only the first match [Test_data_forQry] but I need the qry to get all the data matching with param2
SET param2 = '[Test_data_forQry],[Next_Test_Data]'

Comment: Do you mean you have data in ColumnB that could contain [Test_data_forQry] _or_ [Next_Test_Data] and you want to search on that?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do it by making the left square-bracket a literal.  Try this:

```
declare @table table (column1 varchar(100))
insert @table(column1) values('[square_brackets_1]')
insert @table(column1) values('[square_brackets_2]')
insert @table(column1) values('[square_brackets_3]')
insert @table(column1) values('[square_brackets_4]')
insert @table(column1) values('[square_brackets_5]')

select * from @table

select * from @table where column1 like '[[]square_brackets_5]'
```

reference: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use `"` like this:

```
set @param2 = '"' + REPLACE(@param2, ',' , '","') + '"'
```

> **Note :**
>   `SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER = ON` => Default
>   When `SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER` is `ON`, identifiers can be delimited by double quotation marks, and literals must be delimited by single quotation marks. When `SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER` is `OFF`, identifiers cannot be quoted and must follow all Transact-SQL rules for identifiers.

Comment: Thank you for suggestion. It did not get data.