# Split @XML without joining to another table via node - @d = '1,2,3,4,5' will return 5 rows

Tags: xml, split, sql-server-2008-r2

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/878833/passing-a-varchar-full-of-comma-delimited-values-to-a-sql-server-in-function) beautiful XML function to split comma separated string

```
Declare @Ids varchar(50)
Set @Ids = ‘1,2,3,5,4,6,7,98,234’

DECLARE @XML XML
SET @XML = CAST('<i>' + REPLACE(@Ids, ',', '</i><i>') + '</i>' AS XML)

SELECT * 
FROM
    SomeTable 
    INNER JOIN @XML.nodes('i') x(i) 
        ON  SomeTable .Id = x.i.value('.', 'VARCHAR(MAX)')
```

Is it possible to split the values without joining to SomeTable?

e.g.

```
Declare @Ids varchar(50)
Set @Ids = ‘1,2,3,5,4,6,7,98,234’

DECLARE @XML XML
SET @XML = CAST('<i>' + REPLACE(@Ids, ',', '</i><i>') + '</i>' AS XML)

--SELECT @XML.nodes('i')
--which would need to return

1
2
3
5
4
6
7
98
234
```

Comment: It would be a lot better if the starting point here wasn't a comma separated string. SQL Server has two data types *designed* for holding multiple values - tables and XML. If possible, switch to using one of those as your input.

Comment: Agreed, this is to get rid of the old fn_Split, without creating new table valued parameters.

Answer (score 1):

That's perfectly possible, for example, assuming that you want to return IDs as integer values :

```
Declare @Ids varchar(50)
Set @Ids = '1,2,3,5,4,6,7,98,234'

DECLARE @XML XML
SET @XML = CAST('<i>' + REPLACE(@Ids, ',', '</i><i>') + '</i>' AS XML)

SELECT x.i.value('.', 'INT') as Id 
FROM @XML.nodes('i') x(i)
```