# Comma separated values In An IN statement (SQL)

Tags: sql, sql-server, cross-apply

I have a table with a column of comma separated values,
i want to take them as different values and place inside The In clause of another select statement. i've tried with cross apply but didn't get it working properly

the table (T1) looks like :

```
Empcode Eid Unitcodes
007645  164 UNT111$UNT112$UNT113$
000645  162 UNT100$UNT102$UNT20$UNT97$UNT98$UNT99$UNT136$
002585  163 UNT25$UNT39$
003059  180 UNT76$                                                                                              
000559  165 UNT109$UNT114$UNT166$UNT27$UNT60$UNT103$UNT58$
003049  175 UNT106$UNT54$UNT86$UNT87$UNT130$UNT131$UNT132$
003049  177 UNT51$UNT56$UNT91$UNT92$
```

and i need a query something like :

```
select * from T2 where empcode='abcd' unitcode in ('UNT111','UNT112','UNT113') 
//only that particular emps Unitcodes from the table T1
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I split a string so I can access item x](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2647/how-do-i-split-a-string-so-i-can-access-item-x)

Comment: is other table is partially filled and you wanted to update the table?

Comment: no i just want pull data from the other table with the first table info. @wasipeer

Comment: @JorgeCampos ya, i've seen but i'm looking for a select statement not a big function

Comment: Then this one: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30221479/460557

Comment: @JorgeCampos can we have a query something like that and the result should be input for the IN clause of the main select statement !

Comment: Yes, just subquery it and add your in statement on the outside.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing a varchar full of comma delimited values to a SQL Server IN function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/878833/passing-a-varchar-full-of-comma-delimited-values-to-a-sql-server-in-function)

Comment: thanks for the idea, i've tried that and found a that only the first  unitcode is taking, the original query is as follows

Comment: select UNITCODE from T_UNIT_MSTR where UNITCODE in(
select ParsedData.* 
from t_regionalhr_mstr mt 
cross apply ( select str = mt.unitcode + ',,' ) f1
cross apply ( select p1 = charindex( '$', str ) ) ap1
cross apply ( select p2 = charindex( '$', str, p1 + 1 ) ) ap2
cross apply ( select Nmame = substring( str, 1, p1-1 )                   
where empcode='002585' 
) ParsedData
)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do It in following:

**QUERY**

```
SELECT * 
FROM #test2
WHERE ID IN (
            SELECT LTRIM(RTRIM(m.n.value('.[1]','varchar(8000)'))) AS Unitcodes
            FROM
                (
                SELECT CAST('<XMLRoot><RowData>' + REPLACE(Unitcodes,'$','</RowData><RowData>') + '</RowData></XMLRoot>' AS XML) AS x
                FROM   #test
                )t
            CROSS APPLY x.nodes('/XMLRoot/RowData')m(n)
            )
```

**SAMPLE DATA**

```
CREATE TABLE #test
(
   Empcode INT, 
   Eid INT,
   Unitcodes NVARCHAR(MAX)
)
INSERT INTO #test VALUES                                                                                           
(000559,  165, 'UNT109$UNT114$UNT166$UNT27$UNT60$UNT103$UNT58$'),
(003049,  175, 'UNT106$UNT54$UNT86$UNT87$UNT130$UNT131$UNT132$')

CREATE TABLE #test2
(
   ID NVARCHAR(MAX)
)

INSERT INTO #test2 VALUES
('UNT54'),('UNT130'),('UNT999')
```

**OUTPUT**

```
ID
UNT54
UNT130
```

Comment: ya sure, i appreciate that

Answer (score 0):

Create a function : This function will split your values

```
  Create FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_Split](@text varchar(8000), @delimiter          varchar(20))
   RETURNS @Strings TABLE
  (   
     position int IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
     value varchar(8000)  
    )
  AS
  BEGIN

  DECLARE @index int
  SET @index = -1

      WHILE (LEN(@text) > 0)
     BEGIN 
   SET @index = CHARINDEX(@delimiter , @text) 
  IF (@index = 0) AND (LEN(@text) > 0) 
   BEGIN  
INSERT INTO @Strings VALUES (@text)
  BREAK 
END 
  IF (@index > 1) 
 BEGIN  
  INSERT INTO @Strings VALUES (LEFT(@text, @index - 1))  
  SET @text = RIGHT(@text, (LEN(@text) - @index)) 
 END 
ELSE
 SET @text = RIGHT(@text, (LEN(@text) - @index))
END
 RETURN
 END
```

then write your query

```
select * from T2 where empcode='abcd' unitcode in (fn_Split("yourcomma seprated column",',')
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
select * from T2 where empcode='abcd' unitcode in ('%UNT111%','%UNT112%','%UNT113%')
```

Comment: In statement is not to use as a LIKE statement.

Comment: just giving him an idea

Comment: Well, i need those values to be added dynamically.

Comment: I need a select statement inside that, but that where i got stuck. is there a way with cross apply ??

Comment: you can use select statement

Comment: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/33553/using-a-select-in-a-where-clause-for-another-select