# Return rows where ID is in semicolon separated string from subquery MSSQL

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to query my sql database to return all the rows where the ID is contained in a separate tables column. The list of project IDs is kept in the `Feedback` table in the `Project_ID` Column with datatype varchar. I am trying to return the rows from the `Projects` table where the IDs are kept in the `Project_ID` column with datatype varchar.

I am doing this using the query

```
SELECT * FROM Projects WHERE Project_ID IN (
    SELECT Project_ID FROM Feedback WHERE ID = 268 and Project_ID IS NOT NULL
)
```

When I run this query I am returned with the message:

```
Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '36;10;59' to data type int
```

Comment: SQL Server has two data types *designed* for holding multiple values. Those are XML and *tables*. If you insist on not using either of them and instead stuffing values inside strings, you're going to increasingly encounter issues, because SQL Server doesn't understand the conventions that you invent.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I realise this isn't a very well designed database and it desperately needs restructuring but at the moment this is the situation that I am in. There is a plan to redevelop it in Q2 of this year but until then I'm stuck with this.

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/878833/passing-a-varchar-full-of-comma-delimited-values-to-a-sql-server-in-function) may help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is yet another example of the importance of normalizing your data.
Keeping multiple data points in a single column is almost never the correct design, and by almost never I mean about 99.9999%.

If you can't normalize your database, you can use a workaround like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Projects p
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT Project_ID 
    FROM Feedback F WHERE ID = 268 
    AND Project_ID IS NOT NULL
    AND ';'+ F.Project_ID +';' LIKE '%;'+ CAST(p.Project_ID as varchar) +';%'
)
```

You can't use the `IN` operator since it's expecting a list of values delimited by a comma, while you try to supply it with a single value that is delimited by a semicolon. Even if the values in Project_ID was delimited by a comma it would still not work.

The reason I've added the `;` on each side of the `Project_ID` in both tables is that this way the `LIKE` operator will return `true` for any location it finds the `Projects.Project_Id` inside the `Feedback.Project_Id`. You must add the `;` to the `Projects.Project_Id` to prevent the `LIKE` to return `true` when you are looking for a number that is a partial match to the numbers in the delimited string. Consider looking for 12 in a string containing 1;112;455 - without adding the delimiter to the search value (12 in this example) the `LIKE` operator would return `true`.

Comment: Thanks Zohar, I'm now getting the error message `Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '%;' to data type int.`

Comment: Sorry, I forgot the casting. fixed.

Comment: Worked a charm - Thanks ever so much :)