# Convert int in string to integers in T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, ssms

I need to convert string to integers, but I'm getting a type error.

```
declare @stringinteger nvarchar(255) null;
set @stringinteger='1,2,3,4'

select *
from user
where id in (@stringinteger)
```

The error I get:

> Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '1,2,3,4' to data type int

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parameterize an SQL IN clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/337704/parameterize-an-sql-in-clause)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing a varchar full of comma delimited values to a SQL Server IN function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/878833/passing-a-varchar-full-of-comma-delimited-values-to-a-sql-server-in-function)

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : declaring VARCHAR without (length)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length) - you should **always** provide a length for any `varchar` variables and parameters that you use. Right now, your `@stringinteger` will be **exactly 1 character** long....

Comment: @marc_s you are right,but this is just example that for this reason i am writed just nvarchar

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have two methods to handle this, dynamic SQL and splitting the string.

For the latter, you can use `string_split()` (introduced in SQL Server 2016) or a similar function (they are all over the web, google "string split sql server"):

```
select *
from user
where id in (select cast(value as int) from string_split(@stringinteger, ',')) ;
```

The dynamic SQL looks like:

```
declare @stringinteger nvarchar(255) null;
set @stringinteger = '1,2,3,4';

declare @sql nvarchar(max);
set 'select *
from user
where id in (@stringinteger)';

set @sql = replace(@sql, '@stringinteger', @stringinteger);

exec sp_executesql @sql;
```

Note that in SQL Server, you should always provide a length for character types.  If you leave it out, then the default varies by context -- and your code may not do what you expect.

Comment: i cant use string_split because db cant support string_split. @Gordon Linoff and i tried to set

Comment: Have a concern with the latter, Gordon. You could easily inject into that without validation of `@stringinteger` prior to the `REPLACE`. Imagine if I passed the value `'1,2,3); DROP TABLE user;--'` For the value.

Comment: @MuratCanOĞUZHAN there are plenty of other options out there for String Splitters, as Gordan says. Have a Google of "T-SQL String Splitter".