# Passing id comma separated as string and casting ID in table as varchar showing incorrect result My query attached?

Tags: sql-server, casting, int, varchar, charindex

i am tying to get record by passing string comma separated ids.
My query in where is like,

```
Charindex(cast(v.Status as varchar(8000)), @status)
```

let suppose i pass parameter @status=15. now it will show me all records whose id is  "1", "5"and "15" ?
 I just need record having id = 15 
Hopes for your suggestions 
thanks

EDIT:

I actually use this link for solution,

RBarry Young answer

[Passing a varchar full of comma delimited values to a SQL Server IN function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/878833/passing-a-varchar-full-of-comma-delimited-values-to-a-sql-server-in-function)

Comment: I recommend again that answer. Use a String Splitter (like `STRING_SPLIT`, and XML Splitter or a tally table splitter), or use a Table-Type parameter. Never use a `WHILE` to  split a delimited list; they perform awfully. There are 100's of examples on how to do this on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

Using CSV data in this way is suboptimal, but here is one trick you may try using `LIKE`:

```
WHERE ',' + CAST(v.Status as varchar(8000)) + ',' LIKE '%,' + @status + ',%'
```

The trick works because now, for example, we are comparing `,1,5,15,` against just `,15,` so there is no chance for a mismatch.

I will go on to say that this is really bad table/database design.  You should ideally just be using a `WHERE IN` clause with a list of values.  Or, better yet, get these CSV values normalized and into a separate table.

Comment: yes you are right it is not a good approch but due to lack of time i am usinf this solution. i tried this solution it works thanks.