# Is there any way to convert varchar to int value in sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a query like this when I pass the values into in operator in sql it shows:

> Conversion failed when converting the `varchar` value '3,4,9' to data type `int.`

How can I solve the issue?

```
declare @values varchar(100)
set @values = '3,4,9'
select @values
select * from CmnItemType where ItemTypeID in (@values)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Passing a varchar full of comma delimited values to a SQL Server IN function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/878833/passing-a-varchar-full-of-comma-delimited-values-to-a-sql-server-in-function)

Comment: To answer the title of your question: Yes, you can convert a `VarChar` value, e.g. `'349'`, to an `Int`: `Cast( '349' as Int )`. What integer value do you expect from `'3,4,9'`?

Answer (score 3):

No.  You can use `string_split()` or a similar user-defined function:

```
where itemtypeid in (select try_convert(int, value) from string_split(@values))
```

Answer (score 1):

What I usually do is use table variable, like this one:

```
DECLARE @values TABLE (id INT)
INSERT INTO @values (id) VALUES (3),(4),(9)
SELECT id FROM @values
```

From that, you could simply do a join to your tables.

If you are creating a stored procedure, you can use a TVP to pass parameters, [here is the Microsoft doc on that](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/use-table-valued-parameters-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver15). With a TVP, your code can simply call your SP with a list and you will be able to join it in the SP.

Hope this will help.