# SQL SELECT WHERE field split cointains a number

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with string filed for age of children that separate with ',' or '-' like this

[image]

I want to find items that contain '4' for example 4-9-14 ,  . i want to separate items with ',' or '-' then find '4'

Comment: The real solution here is fix your design

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Turning a Comma Separated string into individual rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5493510/turning-a-comma-separated-string-into-individual-rows)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Passing a varchar full of comma delimited values to a SQL Server IN function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/878833/passing-a-varchar-full-of-comma-delimited-values-to-a-sql-server-in-function)

Comment: What does "find 4" actually mean? Values where it has the character `'4'`? If so, why do you need to split the data? What have ***you*** tried to solve the problem yourself? Why didn't it work? Tthough that doesn't change my point; fix the design. Really, as well, you should  be storing the date of birth, rather than an age. An age value becomes out of date as soon as it's entered, where as a DOB allows you to calculate the age of someone for *any* given date.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You really should fix the data model.  In the absence of that, `like` might be your best choice.  I am thinking:

```
where ' ' + replace(replace(ageOfChildren, ',', ' '), '-', ' ') + ' ' like '% 4 %'
```

This changes the delimiter to `' '` by replacing all commas and hyphens.  It then looks for `' 4 '` after the replacement.

Note the following:

- Storing multiple values in a string is a bad idea.
- Storing numbers in a string is a bad idea.
- Storing ages is a bad idea, because they literally change every day.

You should have a separate table with one row per child and a date that stores the date of birth.

Answer (score 0):

If all you want to do is find rows where the AgeOfChildren column contains the character '4', this query should do it
`SELECT * FROM [table] WHERE AgeOfChildren LIKE '%4%'`

Comment: What if the child is 14? `'14'`  is `LIKE '%4%'`.

Comment: I thought about this, and the OP says they need the character '4'. This is more like a date problem. The data type for the column should be created appropriately and then you can extract the value you need using a better interface.

Comment: @Larnu It will find that. % is like a wild card.

Comment: I know... I *suppose* "find '4'" could be read several ways, including values that contain the number 4, rather than the child is the age 4; but then if that is true there's no need to split the data as the OP describes. At best, the question is unlclear.

Comment: it find 4 14 but i want to find only 4 for example 4-9 or 12,5,4

Answer (score 0):

If you want to first seperate items with comma and dash, then find items with AgeOfChildren 4 :

```
SELECT * FROM [table] 
WHERE AgeOfChildren NOT LIKE '%,%' 
AND 
AgeOfChildren NOT LIKE '%-%' 
AND 
AgeOfChildren LIKE '%4%'
```

Comment: No, i want find items that contains 4, for example 4-9