# How to using STRING_SPLIT within an SSIS OLE DB Source SQL Command when the database compatibility level is set to is set to SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, ssis, etl

I have an SSIS package on server 1. It does a SQL query on SQL db located on server 2 via the OLEDB source sql command text. The query is:

```sql
SELECT * FROM PRODUCTS
WHERE PRODUCT_NAME IN (?)
```

This fails, since? is a scalar value and not a table. To fix this there are 2 options:

1. Use STRING_SPLIT
2. [Create string split function](https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Use-Comma-Separated-Delimited-string-values-with-IN-and-WHERE-clause-in-SQL-Server.aspx)

I can't use option 1 because although it is SQL server 2017, the DB compatibility level is set to 2008 (Level 100). STRING_SPLIT is supported only for a higher compatibility level. I'm not allowed to change this.

I can't use option 2 because I am not allowed to create any new custom functions on that database.

Is there a workaround? I have read about adding the custom function into the master DB, but unsure whether future SQL updates may reset it as user functions are not meant to be placed inside the master DB.

Comment: The reason it's not working is because `NOT IN (?)` would result in `NOT IN ('String1,String2, String3')` would would be equivalent to `= 'String1,String2,String3'`. You need need to split the string in the SQL.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Passing a varchar full of comma delimited values to a SQL Server IN function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/878833/passing-a-varchar-full-of-comma-delimited-values-to-a-sql-server-in-function)

Comment: If you look at my execute SQL task, I have already split the strings such that the parameter have values NOT IN ('String1','String2', 'String3')

Comment: Check your SQL again, @variable . `WHERE PRODUCT_NAME NOT IN (?)`. In that syntax the `?` represents a **scalar** value.

Comment: Alas, [STRING_SPLIT requires the compatibility level to be at least 130](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: Thanks for the help guys but I am in a tricky situation where I can neither use the STRING_SPLIT nor create a custom function to do the split. Any advise will be helpful.

Comment: Instead of using a SQL command in the OLEDB Source - use a variable.  In that variable - create the SQL code as needed, concatenating the values.  Something like: "SELECT * FROM PRODUCTS WHERE PRODUCT_NAME IN (" + @[User::YourParameter] + ")"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### STRING_SPLIT alternative

As mentioned in the following answer [T-SQL split string](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28153222/7031230),
the following SQL query can replace the `STRING_SPLIT` function:

```sql
SELECT LTRIM(RTRIM(Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)'))) 'Value' 
FROM  
(     
SELECT CAST ('<M>' + REPLACE(/*Comma separated value should be placed here*/, ',', '</M><M>') + '</M>' AS XML) AS Data            
) AS A 
CROSS APPLY Data.nodes ('/M') AS Split(a)
```

[image]

#### Using OLE DB Source SQL Command

If you are using an OLE DB Source component, you can use the following SQL Command:

```sql
DECLARE @String varchar(100) = ?;

SELECT * FROM PRODUCTS
WHERE PRODUCT_NAME IN (
SELECT LTRIM(RTRIM(Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)'))) 'Value' 
FROM  
(     
SELECT CAST ('<M>' + REPLACE(@String , ',', '</M><M>') + '</M>' AS XML) AS Data            
) AS A 
CROSS APPLY Data.nodes ('/M') AS Split(a)
)
```

#### Test

Using the `AdventureWorks2017` database, I used the following query to search for the person's information stored in the `[Person].[Person]` table while the filter is on the `PersonType` column:

```sql
DECLARE @String varchar(100) = ?;

SELECT * FROM [AdventureWorks2017].[Person].[Person]
WHERE PersonType IN (
SELECT LTRIM(RTRIM(Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)'))) 'Value' 
FROM  
(     
SELECT CAST ('<M>' + REPLACE(@String , ',', '</M><M>') + '</M>' AS XML) AS Data            
) AS A 
CROSS APPLY Data.nodes ('/M') AS Split(a)
)
```

[image]

In the OLE DB Source Editor, if we click on the *Parameters* button, a parameter is recognized. I will create a new variable and use it as a parameter as shown in the image below:

[image]

The variable data type should be set to `String` and the value is set to `EM,SC` which are both symbols used in the `PersonType` column.

[image]

Now, if we click on the *Preview* button in the OLE DB Source Editor, the accurate data is visualized.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. This works, can I ask whether there is any way to place the results of the split into a temporary table and then use the temp table inside the IN clause? When I try it I get an error - metadata could not be determined because statement ... uses a temp table

Comment: @variable check this solution: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/SqlServer/en-US/8674dddf-730a-4f31-8c1e-d9410337d6f4/temp-table-not-able-to-be-recognized-in-ssis-package?forum=sqlintegrationservices

Comment: That's to get data from temp table, where as what I wanted to ask you was to insert data into temp table as part of the command text.

Comment: @variable You should split the statement into 2 parts: inserting data into a temp table will be done in an Execute SQL Task while reading it is done in the OLE DB Source.

Answer (score 4):

One way would be switch context to a database that *does* have the required compatibility level (`tempdb` below).

```
DECLARE @ProductNames VARCHAR(MAX) = ? 

CREATE TABLE #ProductNames
(
PRODUCT_NAME VARCHAR(50) PRIMARY KEY
)

EXEC tempdb.sys.sp_executesql N'INSERT INTO #ProductNames SELECT DISTINCT value FROM STRING_SPLIT(@ProductNames, '','')',
                       N'@ProductNames VARCHAR(MAX)',
                       @ProductNames = @ProductNames;

SELECT *
FROM   PRODUCTS
WHERE  PRODUCT_NAME IN (SELECT pn.PRODUCT_NAME
                        FROM   #ProductNames pn)

DROP TABLE #ProductNames
```

Comment: It doesn't accept this inside the `OLEDB source sql command text`. It works in management studio.

Comment: @variable - you have provided no details about what doesn't work You could try adding `IF 1= 0 SELECT  * FROM   PRODUCTS` to the top of the current script though. Possibly it is struggling to infer the metadata of the resultset at the moment

Comment: When I click on the parameters button it given message as compile error

Comment: @variable I don't have SSIS dev environment installed as haven't worked with that for years. Maybe try just `EXEC sys.sp_executesql` and adding a `use tempdb` to the start of the SQL Script run by that command

Answer (score 0):

You can load you string into an parameter object @ProductNames and then use that as a source and then inner join the product table in another data flow.

1st DF:
Script Component Source with @stringToParse as a variable. Also have output string in DF of ProductName.

Code:

```
string prods = Variables.stringToParse.Value;
string[] productNames = prods.Split(',');
foreach(string p in productNames)
{
    OutputBuffer0.AddRow();
    OutputBuffer0.ProductName = p;
}
```

Then load the results into a recordset destination mapped to @ProductNames.

2nd DF:
2 sources.

1. Product Table
2. Your recordset @ProductNames

do a merge join (inner) and you will have your records.

Comment: Note: You may need to sort your data before merging.