# Sql split comma separated data and check with other table

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, stored-procedures

I have a one table with 2 fields one for tag and another for ProspectID

```sql
DECLARE @Filter NVARCHAR(251) ='30,40'

declare @temp table
(
    TagID       NVARCHAR(MAX),
    ProspectID  INT
)

INSERT INTO @temp(TAGID,ProspectID)
 
VALUES 

        ('20,30,40' ,1),
        ('30,50' ,2),
        ('20,30,40' ,3),
        ('60,70' ,4),
        ('30' ,5)
```

Need to return **30** contains prospectID and **40** contains as per my example

Output I need

```
ProspectID  
1
3
5
```

Comment: Fix your design; that is the *real* solution.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Turning a Comma Separated string into individual rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5493510/turning-a-comma-separated-string-into-individual-rows)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Passing a varchar full of comma delimited values to a SQL Server IN function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67914697/2029983)

Comment: your question requires more clarity

Comment: By what logic is `2` excluded and `5` included?

Comment: what is the differnce between 2 and 5 in ProspectID, why is 2 is not included in desired result and why is 5 is included in desired result? I think the 1,3 is enough.

Answer (score 0):

**This is a question of [*Relational Division With Remainder*](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/databases/sql-server/t-sql-programming-sql-server/divided-we-stand-the-sql-of-relational-division/),** of which there are many solutions. I will present one common one.

You can use `STRING_SPLIT` to break up your values:

```sql
declare @temp table
(
    TagID       NVARCHAR(MAX),
    ProspectID  INT
)

INSERT INTO @temp(TAGID,ProspectID)
 
VALUES 

        ('20,30,40' ,1),
        ('30,50' ,2),
        ('20,30,40' ,3),
        ('60,70' ,4),
        ('30' ,5)

DECLARE @Filter NVARCHAR(251) ='30,40'

SELECT
  t.ProspectID
FROM @temp t
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
    FROM STRING_SPLIT(@Filter, ',') f
    LEFT JOIN STRING_SPLIT(t.TagID, ',') t ON t.value = f.value
    HAVING COUNT(t.value) = COUNT(*)  -- none missing
);
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=1b35c045d7a2dfaac51b18f633338476)

**However, your schema design is flawed.** Do not store multiple pieces of information in one column or value. Instead store them in separate rows.

So you would have a table `ProspectTag` storing each combination (what you get by splitting the strings into separate rows), and `@Filter` should be a table variable or Table Valued Parameter also.

```
declare @temp table
(
    TagID       int,
    ProspectID  int
);

INSERT INTO @temp (TagID, ProspectID)
VALUES
(20, 1),
(30, 1),
(40, 1),
(30, 2),
(50, 2),
(20, 3),
(30, 3),
(40, 3),
(60, 4),
(70, 4),
(30, 5);

DECLARE @Filter TABLE(value int PRIMARY KEY);
INSERT @Filter (value) VALUES
(30),
(40);

DECLARE @totalFilters int = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @Filter);

SELECT
  t.ProspectID
FROM @temp t
JOIN @Filter f ON t.TagID = f.value
GROUP BY
  t.ProspectID
HAVING COUNT(*) = @totalFilters;  -- none missing
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=30f4678771cef4ec3314b2e541025d32)

Comment: the first query does not yield required *ProspectID =5*

Comment: I know, but there seems no logic in why it was included, and not `2`, so guessing it was a mistake. If OP wants all possible matches then this could be easily modified to use a straight join. Let's wait and see what OP says

Answer (score -1):

use follwing query

```
SELECT ProspectID
FROM @temp
 WHERE TAGID LIKE '%' + @Filter + '%'
 --WHERE TAGID LIKE '%' + LTRIM(RTRIM(@Filter)) + '%'
 or TagID  in (PARSENAME(REPLACE(@Filter,',','.'),2) )--for ProspectID=5
```